# Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 9

Tags: android

I have a problem in updating the SDK with Android SDK Tools, revision 9

I am getting the following error. I have tried reinstalling the SDK but i did not work.

Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 9
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r09-windows.zip

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling HTTPS, and use HTTP for downloading.